# How can i populate a model data while fetching it?Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I have two model's schema, one of them is the `Category` and the other is the `subCategory`. We need the `Category` to create a subCategory model, but the `Category` model doesn't have to have `subCategories`.
This is my `subCategory` model:

```js
const Mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = Mongoose;
// Brand Schema
const SubCategorySchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required:true
  },
  id: {
    type:  Schema.Types.String,
    unique:true,
    required:true
  },
  category: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Category',
    required:true
  },
  updated: Date,
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = Mongoose.model('SubCategory', SubCategorySchema);
```

and this is my `Category` model:

```js
const Mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = Mongoose;

// Category Schema
const CategorySchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
  },
  id: {
    type: String,
    required:true,
    unique: true
  },
  image: {
    type:String,
    default:'http://res.cloudinary.com/wisecart/image/upload/v1616718691/kuy26lytx5k0lkvfkgrt.svg',
    required:true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  updated: Date,
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },

});

module.exports = Mongoose.model('Category', CategorySchema);
```

I'm using
How do I populate subcategories when I request a category?
For example, I want to get a response as

```json
{

  "image": "http://res.cloudinary.com/wisecart/image/upload/v1616718691/kuy26lytx5k0lkvfkgrt.svg",
  "_id": "606605934b213d2887e3a840",
  "name": "Samsung",
  "description": "sama",
  "id": "asa",
  "subCategory": [{Subcategory with an Id of _id},{Subcategory with an Id of _id}],
  "created": "2021-04-01T17:40:35.505Z",
  "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: do you want to populate category field of SubCategorySchema ?

Comment: do you want to populate category field of SubCategorySchema ?

Answer (score 0):

You've to use `aggregation` query

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/ItN9R9AlE4A

Use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

> Performs a left outer join to an unsharded collection in the same database to filter in documents from the "joined" collection for processing. To each input document, the $lookup stage adds a new array field whose elements are the matching documents from the "joined" collection. The $lookup stage passes these reshaped documents to the next stage.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate

```
db.category.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "subCategory", // collection name
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "category",
      "as": "subCategory"
    }
  }
])
```